# Installing a package using Apt get for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud, apt

I was deploying an optical character recognition web application. However, I realized that one of the packages needed to be installed through apt-get rather than pip. I was wondering how I would go about doing this through google app engine? Just for reference, I would like to install:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to install [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) via pip and include it in you requirements.txt for the application you're planning to deploy on app engine (Standard or [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries))?

If the utilization of the pytesseract package is not enough, you can try to deploy an [App Engine Flex Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) service and specify the installation of this package in the [Dockerfile](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#docker) for this service

Comment: I have decided to go the Dockerfile route! It seems to be the most straightforward. Thank you!